# Ruby / Rails pre-epoch dates on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Working with dates in ruby and rails on windows, I'm having problems with pre-epoch dates (before 1970) throwing out of range exceptions. I tried using both [`Time`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) and [`DateTime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) objects, but still have the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need dates (no times), the [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) class in ruby should handle dates before 1970. But it has only a resolution of days. I don't know if there are solutions, if you also need times before 1970
[(source)](http://safari.ibmpressbooks.com/0768667208/ch07lev1sec18)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the section on dates on [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html).  I'm still learning Ruby but it sounds like you could use either the [Civil or Commerical Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html) to go back before 1970.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) class, problem then became making that work with the rails select helper - which didn't happen, just generated the html myself.